# How can I pass the loop.index from a view template to a node template?

Tags: 8, views, theming, nodes

In a views template (views-view-unformatted.twig.html), I have

```
{% for row in rows %}  
    {% set row_index = loop.index0 %}  
    {{ row.content }}  
{% endfor %}
```

where each row is processed in a `node--view.twig.html`.  How can I pass in `row_index` to the `node--view.twig.html`?  This is used simply to create an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the preprocess function in `my_theme.theme`.  In the case above, the row was formatted in `node--view--pagename.html.twig`, so the preprocessor function name is `mytheme_preprocess_node__view__pagename`.  In the function, the view is iterated until the node matches the current node that is being processed, at that point, the row_index is determined and set and accessible in `node--view--pagename.html.twig` as `{{ row_index }}`.

```
function fu_preprocess_node__view__pagename(&$vars) {
    $view = $vars['view'];
    $node = $vars['node'];
    foreach($view->result as $key => $row){
        if($row->nid == $node->id()){
            $vars['row_index'] = $row->index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing.
A small thing however, `$vars['view']` isn't available so you should try `$view = views_get_current_view();`